# how to keep session alive

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

when the users is working on the open office ( letter editing tool)popup, application screen is displaying timeout

Initial Analysis
if the users are working on the open office for more than 60 minutes - the server are not refreshed to extend the session.( session is active behind)

We have idletime set in web.xml

Please help me out in resolving how to keep session alive.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a keep alive request solution for this in the past. Basically you set a JavaScript timeout for some long duration less than your session timeout, usually half to three-quarters of your session timeout. When the JavaScript timeout fires make an ajax request to a controller on the server that participates in the session. This will make the server think you are still active and should keep the server session alive by resetting it.

Also, you will need to reset the JavaScript timeout when your ajax response is received to start the timer again.

PS: You don't really need to do anything in the backend controller, you are just poking the session to keep it alive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use -1 instead of 60 in web.xml as:

```
<session-config>
     <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

if you don't want to increase session time out then you can find work-around as :

run your task in a dedicated thread which touches (extends) the session while working or notifies the user when the thread has finished

Comment: This makes all sessions never expire, which is a very bad idea, especially if you actually store data in session.

Comment: @cjstehno : then in that case we can create one watcher task that will ping after 30 minutes to keep session alive.

Comment: @cjstehno : yes that might be the one of the case.